# set multiple PATH variables in CMD

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cmd, path-variables

I'm working in a non-admin environment and I need to get a vue project running. 
To do this, I need to set both the path to node and to npm. Here are the two paths:

E:\nodejs

E:\npm

If I set these one by one, like so:

```
set PATH="E:\nodejs"
set PATH="E:\npm"
```

The first configuration is overwritten by the second, so I'm either lacking the scope for the npm or the nodejs directory.

I googled it and I found multiple solutions like here:
https://superuser.com/questions/23048/setting-multiple-environment-variables-in-a-shell-spawned-via-windows-batch-scri

But I dont really know if they do what I actually need.

To do what I described above inside a CMD, what command do I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set PATH=%PATH%;E:\nodejs;E:\npm`

Comment: Better would be `if "%PATH:~-1%" == ";" (set "PATH=%PATH%E:\nodejs;E:\npm") else set "PATH=%PATH%;E:\nodejs;E:\npm"`. Appending the two paths to already existing __local__ `PATH` without or with an additional semicolon is not really important, but the additional double quotes left to variable name `PATH` and at end of the cmd line could be very important if existing value of `PATH` contains for example a folder path with an `&`. In this case the double quotes are important to get the ampersand in folder path interpreted as literal character and not as AND operator for two commands on one line.